# laravel second Auth screen after Login

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I have this Laravel Project where i want to click login and after that it should display  another page which says confirm login then the user would be able to see the rest of the page

my problem is that i can not redirect after i press login to another page `SecondLogin.blade.php`

i have tried changing the `$redirectTo` in the LoginController but it does not seem to work it keeps redirecting to the `/home` page

futhermore i am just using the default login features from laravel.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 places where Laravel  redirects to '/home' by default:

middleware - app/Http/Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated
controller - app/Http/Controller/Auth/LoginController
controller - app/Http/Controller/Auth/RegisterController

```
<?php // middleware

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect('/home');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

---

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';
```

---

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';
```

So try to change them all out.

Comment: i cant seem to get it working i changed the ```/home``` to ```/welcome``` but doesnt work